# Disabling doc list when using ctrl-tab in Notepad++

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, tabs

I'Is there a way to disable the "doc list" that is displayed when you switch between documents with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>?

I'm used to editplus, where hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> simply switches the document immediately.

This is useful to quickly switch between several documents and find the one you want by content instead of by name.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open **Settings** → **Preferences** from the menu.

Click the **MISC.** tab. Find the **Document Switcher** box in the upper right. Uncheck **Enable**.

Your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> now just slides through documents.

[image: Document switcher settings]

Comment: @phuclv I just saw your edit to this answer from last year. Thank you very much for adding an updated screenshot!