# Enabling MRU tabbing in Notepad++ but without the "document switcher" popup?

Tags: notepad++, tabs

I like the MRU (Most Recently Used) tabbing order of Notepad++, but really dislike the "document switcher" that pops up when you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

When I disable the document switcher option in Settings -> Misc, it also disables the MRU behaviour, for some unknown reason. Is there some manual tweak / trick to keep MRU without the doc switcher popup?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/201001/disabling-doc-list-when-using-ctrl-tab-in-notepad

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling doc list when using ctrl-tab in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/201001/disabling-doc-list-when-using-ctrl-tab-in-notepad)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but since it keeps popping up on Google search results I thought I'd answer it.

Yes, in the latest NP++ versions you CAN disable the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> switch window and just have the MRU switch behavior you expect.

**Just go to:**

*Settings > Preferences > MISC. > Document Switcher*: uncheck *Enable*

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will continue working, but the popup will not appear.

[image: Document switcher settings]

Comment: The shortcut is `Ctrl+Tab`, not `Alt+Tab`

Comment: Thanks, however in my install (v8.3.3, 64 bit, Win 10) the settings are the same as before - disabling doc switcher also disables MRU behaviour (https://i.imgur.com/ssIxzi5.png)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no tweak at the moment. If you are a programmer, you can inspect N++ source code to confirm.